# Directory that apache can write to from PHP but will not serve files from

Tags: php, .htaccess, unix, permissions

I need to provide an unshared upload using php on apache on linux.

I can handle file uploads just fine, and move them to the desired folder. What I wanted to ask was how can I make it so that even if someone knew that folder and the filename, they could never download the file through a browser.

In other words, I need apache to be able to move the file to the folder, but to be unable to serve files from that folder.

Can php write to files outside the docroot? Is there something I can do with htaccess? Or even just linux directory permissions?

I was about to create a blank index.html and give the files a name containing a long random string (to make them unguessable) but decided there must be a better way.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upload your files outside the Apache DocumentRoot.

I.E.

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/public/
```

(where your php files are)

And upload in **/var/www/uploads/**

Comment: so am i correct in thinking that even if the www-data user (the user that apache is running as) theoretically has access to that folder (according to linux permissions), it cannot read that folder because it is outside the docroot? whereas PHP behaves more as a logged-in user at a shell?

Comment: Apache will be able to read it (so you will be able to use the file with PHP), but they will never be served outside, Apache will only serve what's inside the documentRoot to your visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Yours is hardly a new problem -- numerous people (yours truly included) have at some point found their "upload" directories used by various file-traders... Fortunately, the solution is simple...

You can make Unix (and, I'm sure, Windows too) files and directories *writable* for a user or a group, but not *readable*. It is sometimes called "negative permissions", and some misguided individuals (and the scripts they create) frown at such settings, but there is nothing wrong with them.

For example, here is an actual file from my server. I ("mi") own it, and the group "www" (which httpd is running under) can *write* to it. But it can not *read* from it. All other legitimate users on the system can read it (which you may or may not want for your setup):

```
-rw--w-r--  1 mi    www    ....  /home/mi/public_html/.../download.log
```

The octal mode (for use with chmod) for the above settings is 0624. You can alter it to suit your needs. For example, if no other user on the system should be able to access the file at all, you'd use 0620...

You can also play with Apache's permission-settings to prevent serving from the directory, but that's far less straightforward than Unix file-system permissions. It will also mean additional work should you ever switch from Apache to a different web-server, or move from running PHP inside Apache to an application server, or whatever...